# Including WCF RIA Services to an existing Silverlight Project

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services, ria, blend

I want to include WCF RIA services to an already existing Silverlight Pproject that was created with MS Expression Blend. Whenever I search the web for information about creating WCF RIA services I only find tutorials about creating a solution by creating a new project with Visual Studio 2010.

I know how to create a new Silverlight application with RIA services using Visual Studio 2010, but I can't find a tutorial on how to include a RIA service after creating a Silverlight project. Is it maybe not possible to do so?

Every bit of help is welcome. Thank you in advance and please excuse my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your Silverlight project configuration and add a "WCF RIA Services link".

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707372%28v=vs.91%29.aspx).

Comment: Hello ken2k. After reading the article you linked here I guess my solution should be like this: I need to create a new Silverlight project which enables RIA services. After creating this new Silverlight project I can get back to the old one and from there I add a link to the new one that enables RIA services. Is this the correct way to approach my problem? Thank you for your quick answer.